# How to find index of Array which the array contains dictionaries in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

if I define array as like this means

```
var tempArray = [String]()
tempArray = ["Hai", "Hello", "How are you?"]
let indx = tempArray.index(of:"Hai")
```

there is an option

> index(of:)

to find index but if I define like this means

```
var tempArray = [AnyObject]() 
//or 
var tempArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()()
```

there is no option to find **index**

Comment: How do you finding object in dictionary, are you expecting object with some specific key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift.swift you can see this declaration:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element : Equatable {
    public func index(of element: Self.Iterator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}
```

This method is available only for array with Equatable elements; AnyObject doesn't conform to Equatable

EDITED:

you can, though, look for your element like this:

```
    var tempArray = [AnyObject]()
    for item in tempArray {
       if let typedItem = item as? SomeYourType {
          if typedItem == searchItem {

          }
       }
    }
```

EDITED:

for removing you can use something like this (not tested):

```
someArr.filter({object in guard let typedObject = (object as? YourType) else {return true}; return typedObject != yourObject })
```

Comment: Actually, I want remove the particular object from array. Without finding index how can I remove that object from array?